I need to write a script to update duplicate entries to the original line of date. I am using google sheets/Forms
copy of column heads
I need it to update the names in Column A with any new data that is entered with same name from google forms that adds to the Data sheet from Form Responses 1 sheet.   I have tired several times and can't get it to work. I don't know how or what is supposed to go in these areas
Code Outline 
